# django call_command migrate seems to kill the process

Tags: python, django

**I do this in my view.py**

```
import os  
import django  
from django.core import management  

def runmigrate(self, databasename): 

    try:
        print('0')
        os.chdir(os.getcwd())
        management.call_command('makemigrations')
        print('1')
        django.setup()
        management.call_command('migrate', app_label='client', database=databasename, interactive=False)
        print('2')
        return "success"
    except Exception as e:
        print(e.args[0])
        return "failure"
```

**but when i call this method in the front end, the terminal shows that**

0
No changes detected
1
Operations to perform:
    Apply all migrations: client
Running migrations:
    Applying client.0001_initial... OK
Performing system checks...

The success label '2' never shows and No error messages are shown.
it seems that the process is killed and every command after it will not be executed.

Answer (score 0):

I might need more code to review but it seems that you are calling self on a def that is not part of a class. I'm not sure what django version you are using but adding `skip_checks=True` to the the call_command should fix this issue since it seems to be hanging on system checks.

```
import os  
import django  
from django.core import management  

def runmigrate(databasename): 
    try:
        print('0')
        os.chdir(os.getcwd())
        management.call_command('makemigrations')
        print('1')
        django.setup()
        management.call_command('migrate', app_label='client', database=databasename, interactive=False, skip_checks=True)
        print('2')
        return "success"
    except Exception as e:
        print(e.args[0])
        return "failure"
```

Comment: If I add the skip_checks=True, this time my front end will say that                           
 'This page isn’t working
127.0.0.1 didn’t send any data' and my back end still give me the same output. @Mitchell, this is a function inside a class.